# Filter specific data with unique pattern in CSV file and move that data to a new column on the same row

Tags: excel, linux, shell, csv

Here is my sample data in csv format. The actual data is way more than this.

This is the data in text based so that you can try it on your own.

Actual data on Ms Excel (csv/xlsx format) can be seen in screenshot below.

```
[24/09/2018:22:41:49 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_BA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=1198 cs-categories="Technology/Internet" cs-host=shavar.services.mozilla.com cs-ip=y.y.y.y cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=60 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:45:44 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=152450 cs-categories="Business/Economy" cs-host=cvshipping.ups.com cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=268 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:44:03 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=1795 cs-categories="Software Downloads" cs-host=blocklist.addons.mozilla.org cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=61 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:41:44 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=3882 cs-categories="Web Ads/Analytics" cs-host=cebwa.d2.sc.omtrdc.net cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=35 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[20/09/2018:15:48:50 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=a.a.a.a cs-auth-group=Domain%20Users cs-bytes=227 cs-categories="Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious" cs-host=data35.adlooxtracking.com cs-ip=b.b.b.b cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" cs-username=johndoe duration=0 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[20/09/2018:15:48:35 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=a.a.a.a cs-auth-group=Domain%20Users cs-bytes=3201 cs-categories="Search Engines/Portals" cs-host=www.google.com cs-ip=b.b.b.b cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=117 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED
```

[image]

Each lines contain `cs-categories=""` as highlighted it has different values such as`Technology/Internet`, `Non-Viewable/Infrastructure`, `Technology/Internet;Web Ads/Analytics`, `Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious` ... just to name a few.

My objective is to take `cs-categories=""` with it’s value and put it to another column … on the same row/line.

This is tricky as `cs-categories=""` located in the middle of the data and the values are varies.
As example:

```
cs-categories="Technology/Internet"
cs-categories="Non-Viewable/Infrastructure"
cs-categories="Technology/Internet;Web Ads/Analytics"
cs-categories="Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious"
```

I’ve also tried to move this data in Linux and try accomplish the same thing using shell command such as grep unique string but didn't work very well at the moment.

The main goal is to get timestamp, the URL and category from this log.

If other solution in Shell script, Python or others are easier, please let me know too.

Comment: Can you show an input sample as text, not a picture? Can you show the expected output for it?

Comment: @choroba, post updated with text based data & better screenshot. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -r 's/^(\[[^\]*\]) (.* cs-categories=")([^"]*)(".*cs-host=)([^ ]*) /\1 \3 \5 \2\3\4\5 /'
 #           \1                  \2           \3          \4      \5
 #       Timestamp                        Categories             Host
```